# Open a web page from a Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a simple web page using angular where a user can type HTML codes in a text box and when I press button it should be open in a new tab or new window. I saved the html content in a variable in $scope. But I have no idea how to load that in to a new window. Can someone direct me?

Comment: You can send html data to your server, save there, open a new window, access that file directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete T.J answer, something like this should work :

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.createHTML = function(html) {
        console.log(html)
        var newWindow = $window.open();
        newWindow.document.writeln(html);
        newWindow.document.close();
    }
}
```

the html:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="html-form" ng-submit="createHTML(html)" class="form" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">HTML</label>
            <textarea ng-model="html" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create HTML" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an Angular-specific answer here, but if you have the HTML in a string, you can do this (in response to a user action, like a button click) to open a new window/tab and write the HTML to it:

```
var wnd = window.open();
wnd.document.write(yourHTMLString);
```

Here's a complete example (without Angular): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/tapoya)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>New Window with HTML Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="theHTML" cols="50" rows="10">
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Popup</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi there!</p>
</body>
</html>
</textarea>
<br><input type="button" id="theButton" value="Show">
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
      var html = document.getElementById("theHTML").value;

      var wnd = window.open();
      wnd.document.write(html);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```